# What's the difference between the tetrad and vierbein fields (local inertial coordinates)?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, definition

I'm studying the formalism of gravity with torsion, the Einstein-Cartan (EC) theory, and i've encountered this book by H. Kleinert "Gauge fields in condensed matter", in which he derives the basic framework of EC theory [in part 4].

When defining the basic differential geometric quantities, he does it all in term of a tetrad basis. Naively speaking the tetrad is defined as a connection between the Minkowski space and the curved one, and in fact he uses the tetrad to define define both torsion and curvature of the affine connection (also defined in terms of tetrad) and of course the metric. Namely the curvature is defined by

$$R_{\mu \nu \lambda \rho} = e_{a \rho} ( \partial_{\mu}\partial_{\nu} - \partial_{\nu}\partial_{\mu} ) e^{a}_{\lambda}. (1)$$

Later when talking about spinors in a curved manifold he invokes the notion of a local basis field, the vierbein, $h_{\alpha \mu}$, that satisfies the same properties of the tetrad, such as

$$ g_{\mu \nu} = e_{a \mu} e^{a}_{\nu} (2.1)$$
$$ g_{\mu \nu} = h_{a \mu} h^{a}_{\nu}.(2.2)$$

Also the tetrad and the vierbein components are related via a Lorentz transformation. For me the problem arises when he says that if we want to define the curvature tensor in terms of the vierbein field, we would always get zero, that is:

$$R_{\mu \nu \lambda \rho} = h_{\alpha \rho} ( \partial_{\mu}\partial_{\nu} - \partial_{\nu}\partial_{\mu} ) h^{\alpha}_{\lambda} = 0. (3)$$

I understand that they are different objects, and in this language the tetrad is just a coordinate transformation that does not obey the integrability condition and the vierbein connects the manifold with the tangent plane at each point.

But in practice how do I tell them apart? I mean, **given a metric, how do i obtain the tetrad and vierbein such that they satisfy the integrability conditions (1) and (3)?**

EDIT: as suggested, here are the definitions the book gives of tetrad and local basis.
notation:
${\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta...}$ = indices in the tangent plane

${\mu, \nu, \rho...}$ = spacetime indices
latin letters = minkowski indices
The vierbein field is defined as a "differential coordinate transformation"
$$dx^\alpha = dx^\mu h^\alpha_\mu,$$
but it is worth noting that the integrability condition (3) is part of the definition.

The tetrad field is presented as:
$$e_\mu = e^a_\mu e_a = \frac{\partial x^a}{\partial x^\mu}e_a$$

where the coordinate transformation $x^a = x^a(x^\mu)$ satisfy the relation
$$(\partial_\mu \partial_\nu - \partial_\nu \partial_\mu)x^a \neq 0.$$
In this sense that i said the tetrad is defined as a connection between minkowski spacetime to the curved one. The thing I'm calling vierbein are also said to be *non-holonomic coordinates*.
**The whole thing is that they obey the same properties (except for the integrability condition) and that confuses me on how to tell them apart in a practical situation.**

Comment: What do you mean? Tetrad and vierbein are different names for the [same](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrad_formalism) [thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame_fields_in_general_relativity).

Comment: @Qmechanic that's the whole point of my question hahah. They are mostly defined as having the same components. But this book defines them as different objects (reasonable) and address different integrability conditions for them.

Comment: That seems to be non-standard terminology.

Comment: Well, good luck getting clarifications on terminology in ECT, as I (who lack your own proficiency in reading its notation) have been trying for months to get an "ECT" tag added to those available.  Although it's 10 or 15 yrs. newer than GR (then perhaps the only other relativistic theory of gravity), it's not popular:  The main reason's probably its more complex math, but another is Einstein's loss to Bohr in the EPR debate of the mid-1930's.  It takes a reputation of 1,000 to establish  a tag, but I doubt if many high-rep regulars on the site are familiar with the procedure needed.

Comment: Nikodem J. Poplawski's many 2009-2010 papers (mostly available free on Arxiv, but with many also published in the printed journals favored by PSE) have often left a wait for replies to ECT-based questions a waste of time on the site, in spite of his cosmology's use of ECT and its spatially-extended fermions to arrive at an implication of local universes on sequentially-decreasing scales with an interesting resemblance to the "quantum foam" hypothesized by Wheeler.  This is an English-language site, and institutional links to the state and private American university systems may be a factor.

Comment: This question might be clearer if you stated the author's *definitions* of the tetrad and the vierbein.

Comment: @Qmechanic the vierbein is defined in page 1398 and the tetrad is introduced in page 1339.

Comment: There's also a third possibility - and you don't need to know German or Greek - just English - an orthogonal field frame. Or in the spirit of Cartan, a moving orthogonal field frame.

Answer (score 2):

In the physics literature there  is a lot of notational confusion caused by failing to distinguish between geometric tensor objects and their numerical components.  Let start with a manifold $M$ equiped with a local coordinate system $x^\mu$. We define  define a vector field to be an object like ${\bf V}=V^\mu(x) {\boldsymbol \partial}_\mu$ where the
$${\boldsymbol \partial}_\mu\equiv \frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu}
$$ are the basis vectors of the tangent space $T(m)_x$ at the point $x$. The $V^\mu$ are componts of the basis indepenedent object ${\bf V}$.  Now we can introduce a set of vector fields  ${\bf e}_a= e_a^\mu(x) {\boldsymbol\partial }_\mu$ and if they are linearly independent and span $T(M)_x$ at all $x$ we can use them as a basis and write  ${\bf V}= V^a(x){\bf e}_a$. The $V^a$ are the  components of ${\bf V}$ with respect to this *frame field*. In four dimensions relativists  call the ${\bf e}_a$ a *vierbein* from the German *vier*=four, *bein=leg*. In three dimensions we would have a  *drei*bein and an one diemsnion an *ein*bein. In general we have a *vielbein* (many legs).

We can play the same game with the cotangent spaces $T^*(M)_x$ with  coordinate basis  ${\bf dx}^\mu$ dual to the ${\boldsymbol\partial}_\mu$ (Most people don't use boldface here, just writing $dx^\mu$ but I am doing so to distinguish tensor objects from their components). A covariant vector field  ${\bf A}$(a section of $T^*(M)$)   can be expandend as  ${\bf A}= A_\mu(x) {\bf dx}^\mu$. If we    introduce a co-frame ${\bf e}^{*a}= e^{*a}_\mu {\bf dx}^\mu$  dual to the ${\bf e}_a$ (this means that ${\bf e}^{*a}({\bf e}_b)= \delta^a_b$),  then we have ${\bf A}= A_a(x) {\bf e}^{*a}$, where $A_a= e_a^\mu A_\mu$.

In casual use people call the arrys of numbers $e^\mu_a$ or the $e^{*a}_\mu$ "vierbeins". They also often don't bother to  put the star on $e^{*a}_\mu$ just writing $e^a_\mu$ and trusting that the Greek and Roman letters serve to distinguish between the components of the frame and the co-frame.  This is OK in many places but is $e^3_2$ a component of a frame or a coframe?

Using the co-frame one can write the metric ${\bf g}$ as either
$$
{\bf g}= g_{\mu\nu}(x) {\bf dx}^\mu\otimes {\bf dx}^\nu
$$
or
$$
{\bf g}= \eta_{ab} {\bf e}^{*a}\otimes {\bf e}^{*b}.
$$
It is common to choose the coframe so that the  the $\eta_{ab}$'s become  constants.
The inner product  ${\bf g}({\bf V},{\bf W})$ evaluates to either $g_{\mu\nu}V^\mu W^\nu$ or $\eta_{ab}V^aW^b$ when one usues ${\bf dx}^\mu({\boldsymbol \partial}_\nu)= \delta^\mu_\nu$ or ${\bf e}^{*a}({\bf e}_b)= \delta^a_b$.

From what you say, it seems as though Hagen K treats the numerical array $e^\mu_a$ as if the were components of a tensor and feels free to raise and lower induces using the metric. These numbers are a set of change-of-basis coefficients and  *not* the components of a  tensor, however,  and this abuse of notation poses serious risks. I recommend not to do it.

Now to EC theory: In the teleparallel EC formalism  we simply choose frame ${\bf e}_a$ and declare  it to be everywhere parallel. "Everwhere parallel" means that the "spin connection" coefficients ${\omega^b}_{a\mu}$ defined by
$$
\nabla_X {\bf e}_a= {\bf e}_b {\omega^b}_{a\mu} X^\mu
$$  are all zero.

In  the coordinate frame we define the Christoffel symbols in the usual way as  the derivative the coordinate frame basis vectors
$$
\nabla_X {\boldsymbol \partial}_\mu =  {\Gamma^\lambda}_{\mu\nu} X^\nu{\boldsymbol \partial}_\lambda.
$$
Using ${\boldsymbol \partial}_\mu = e^{*a}_\mu {\bf e}_a$ we evaluate
$$
\nabla_X {\boldsymbol \partial}_\mu = (\nabla_X e^{*a}_\mu) {\bf e}_a+ e^{*a}_\mu\nabla_X {\bf e}_a\\
= (X^\nu \partial_\nu e^{*a}_\mu) {\bf e}_a+0\\
=  e^{*\lambda}_a (X^\nu \partial_\nu e^{*a}_\mu){\boldsymbol\partial}_\lambda
$$
to read off that
$$
{\Gamma^\lambda}_{\mu \nu}= e^\lambda_a\partial_\nu e^{*a}_\mu.
$$
In this calculation we have used that the covaraint derivative is a *derivation* (obeys Leibnitz rule) and  observed that the $e^{*a}_{\mu}$ are just numbers  so $\nabla_X e^{*a}_{\mu}\equiv  X^\nu \partial_\nu e^{*a}_{\mu}$.

In my option this teleparallel game is a total waste of time. We are obscuring what is going on by making a   completely arbitrary choice of the ${\bf e}_a$ that we are going to call parallel.

Edit: the equation ${\bf g}= \eta_{ab} {\bf e}^{*a}\otimes {\bf e}^{*b}
$ was originally typed as $ {\bf g}= \eta_{ab} {\bf e}^{*a}\otimes {\bf e}^{*n}$

Comment: I feel it is important to note that either the vierbein and tetrad, in the language of the book, have inverse and are defined as different objects. **The problem is** how to distinguish them in a practical situation since they must differ by the integrability condition posed. 

about the EC: yeah, in teleparallell they obey the integrability condition because the curvature vanishes. I dont know what you mean by "EC is simply a confusing rewriting of standard GR", i'm sorry.

Comment: I'll amend my answer.

Comment: sorry, but I still do not understand how to tell the fields apart, or if there is a way to tell them to be the same ignoring the integrability conditions. In the beggining of my question i pointed that I was studying the EC theory, i suppose you're talking about teleparalelism, which is not the same thing. EC theory, in general, consider both curvature AND torsion as non-vanishing.

Comment: The vierbein and the tetrad are just different names for the same thing. I do not have have Keinert's book, but I expect that he wrote different chapters at different times and so used different names for the same object.  Your other equations do not make sense, so I think you are misunderstanding something.  I suggest that you read some other source on EC.

Comment: Are the $\mu$ component of the $a$ element of the 1-form orthonormal basis $e^a_{\ \ \mu}$ numerically equal to the $a$ component of the $\mu$ element of the vector coordinate basis $e_\mu^{\ \ a}$? Most references denote both objects as $e^a_\mu$

Answer (score 0):

This answer only addresses the integrability condition.

It doesn't address the calculation of Jacobi identity, the Riemann curvature tensor or the Second Bianchi identity.

I'm assuming a Riemann-Cartan space-time, namely, $Dg=0$ and $T\neq0$, where $D$ is the covariant derivative (typically denoted by $\nabla$) using an affine connection, and $g$ is the metric tensor which is assumed compatible with the connection. Since $T$ is the non-zero it excludes the Levi-Civita connection.

And I'm using Latin letters where $a,b,c,d$ for the field frame indices and $i,j,k,l$ for the space-time indices.

If you start with a metric, then you need to ensure the connection is compatible with the metric, i.e., $Dg=0$.

Otherwise, the first thing you will need is a connection $1$-form, namely

$$\Gamma^a_{\;b}=\Gamma^a_{ib}dx^i.$$

Then the curvature matrix based on the connection is defined as

$$\Omega\equiv d\Gamma + \Gamma\wedge\Gamma$$

or in component form, $$\Omega^a_{\;b}=\Gamma^{a}_{\;b}+ \Gamma^{a}_{\;c}\wedge\Gamma^{c}_{\;b} $$ and is called the structure equation or the curvature $2$-form - which can be shown to transform as a tensor.

The exterior derivative of the structure equation is the integrable condition

$$d\Omega=\Omega \wedge \Gamma-\Gamma \wedge \Omega$$

where the commutator of covariant derivatives based on the affine connections must satisfy the Jacobi identity.

The structure equation can be written in terms of the Riemann curvature tensor

$$\Omega^a_{\;b}=\frac{1}{2} R^a_{bjk} dx^j\wedge dx^k$$

noting $R^a_{bjk}$ is a $(1,3)$ tensor and $\Omega^a_{\;b}$ is a $(1,1)$ tensor.

In this case, the exterior derivative of the structure equation must satisfy the Second Bianchi identity.

This is a typical pattern of Cartan - differential forms with tensor valued coefficients.

Comment: $\Omega^a_{\;b}=\Gamma^{a}_{\;b}+ \Gamma^{a}_{\;c}\wedge\Gamma^{c}_{\;b}$ should be $\Omega^a_{\;b}=d\Gamma^{a}_{\;b}+ \Gamma^{a}_{\;c}\wedge\Gamma^{c}_{\;b}$, you missed a $d$.

Answer (score 0):

A vielbein - which is the generic term for $n$ dimensions, with "vierbein" being the case where $n = 4$ - is a generalization of the coordinate frame
$$\left(∂_μ ≡ \frac{∂}{∂x^μ}: 0 ≤ μ < n\right)$$
to
$$\left(e_a ≡ e_a^μ ∂_μ: 0 ≤ a < n\right).$$
(where I'm using the Einstein Summation Convention here and below).

A tetrad, for $n = 4$ (I don't know what the generic name is, for other $n$), generalizes the coordinate co-frames
$$\left(dx^μ: 0 ≤ μ < n\right)$$
to
$$\left(h^a ≡ h^a_μ dx^μ: 0 ≤ a < n\right).$$

The matrices $e = \left(e_a^μ: 0 ≤ a,μ < n\right)$ or $h = \left(h^a_μ: 0 ≤ a,μ < n\right)$ are always assumed to be invertible, so that their counterpart can be defined as the respective inverse: $e = h^{-1}$ or $h = e^{-1}$.

I don't know how much the usage for "vierbein" and "tetrad" coincide with the use I made with them, above; other than that "vierbein" and "vielbein" are used with frames, not co-frames, as far as I'm aware.

But in any case, frames and co-frames are not the same thing. They are different kinds of objects.

And no: you can *not* define a metric from either, alone. You need an additional object for that: either a "frame metric" and a corresponding line element for the co-frame
$$g_{ab} = g\left(e_a, e_b\right), \quad g = g_{ab} h^a h^b,$$
or the dual metric for the co-frame
$$g^{ab} = \tilde g\left(h^a, h^b\right).$$
Only then can you define a metric or its dual:
$$g_{μν} = g_{ab} h^a_μ h^b_ν, \quad g^{μν} = g^{ab} e^μ_a e^ν_b.$$

To be able to define a metric would require either a *second* set of frame vectors or frame co-vectors:
$$h_a = h_{aν} dx^ν, \quad e^a = e^{aν} ∂_ν.$$
Then you could define the metric or dual metric in all of its forms:
$$
g_{μν} = h^a_μ h_{aν}, \quad g^{μν} = e^{aμ} e_a^ν,\\
g_{ab} = e_a^μ h_{bμ}, \quad g^{ab} = e^{aμ} h^b_μ.
$$
Conversely, having either a frame metric or co-frame metric allows you to define the second set of frames or co-frames.

It's actually more general than the converse direction, since there is no requirement built in that the metric constructed using the second set of frames or co-frames even be symmetric. The symmetry requirement can be expressed as:
$$h_a ∧ h^a ≡ h_a ⊗ h^a - h^a ⊗ h_a = 0, \quad e_a ∧ e^a ≡ e_a ⊗ e^a - e^a ⊗ e_a = 0.$$

Bear in mind that you can also have a geometry where the metric and its dual have to be treated independently because they're each non-invertible. That's the case for the Newton-Cartan geometry that underlies [Newton-Cartan Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%E2%80%93Cartan_theory), where the metric and its dual have the respective forms:
$$g = h^0 ⊗ h^0, \quad \tilde g = e_1 ⊗ e_1 + e_2 ⊗ e_2 + e_3 ⊗ e_3,$$
with the flat space-time version
$$g = dt ⊗ dt, \quad \tilde g = \frac{∂}{∂x} ⊗ \frac{∂}{∂x} + \frac{∂}{∂y} ⊗ \frac{∂}{∂y} + \frac{∂}{∂z} ⊗ \frac{∂}{∂z},$$
encoding the geometric invariants that characterize the non-relativistic chrono-geometry:
$$dt^2, \quad \left(\frac{∂}{∂x}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{∂}{∂y}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{∂}{∂z}\right)^2.$$
In that case, the second set of frames and co-frames are degenerate. For this example, you'd have:
$$\left(h_0, h_1, h_2, h_3\right) = \left(0, h^1, h^2, h^3\right), \quad \left(e^0, e^1, e^2, e^3\right) = \left(e_0, 0, 0, 0\right).
$$

So, these objects are not all interchangeable - on principle alone.